# Angular $location undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting an undefined error for $location. I've been staring at this for too long and need an extra pair of eyes to tell me what I am doing wrong. Thank you.

Controller Example:

```
myApp.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', 'GeolocationSvc', '$http', '$location', function ($scope, geolocation, $http, $location, uiGmapGoogleMapApi)

    $scope.test = function ($location){
       $location.search('test', 0);
    }
]);
```

Error:

> Cannot read property 'search' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `$location` from `search` function `parameter`, By having `$location` parameter over there killing the existence of `$location` dependency instance inside a function.

```
$scope.test = function (){
   $location.search('test', 0);
}
```

Comment: @clo_ Glad to help you, Thanks :)

Comment: I used your method. My URL already contained the test param with a value of 1. This method added #?test=0 to the end of my current url. I simply want to update the current test param or add it if it does not exist. Do you think this is this the right method?

Answer (score 0):

No need to pass it into the function:

```
myApp.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', 'GeolocationSvc', '$http', '$location', function ($scope, geolocation, $http, $location, uiGmapGoogleMapApi)

    $scope.test = function (){
       $location.search('test', 0);
    }
]);
```